# Unable to locate xpath in head element

Tags: xpath, automation, css-selectors, automated-tests

I am fairly new in automation. Somehow I wanted to get the xpath/locator for the 'keywords' for this and add .toHaveAttribute assertion but my problem is I cant locate the correct xpath for the keywords:

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Empower your business to function onshore and offshore as one enterprise with Unient's versatile range of services and regional service delivery capabilities."
<meta name="keywords" content="Unient, bpo company, outsource company, bpo company philippines, bpo outsource, one outsource, offshoring australia, outsourcing philippines, outsourced bpo, bpo companies"
```

I tried using:
page.locator("meta[name='keywords']"   but it doesn't work, now I tried this other scenario:

1. open view page source
2. inspect element and use this selector: but still doens't work

   page.locator("td[value='130']");
       <meta name="keywords" content="Unient, bpo company, outsource company, bpo company philippines, bpo outsource, one outsource, offshoring australia, outsourcing philippines, outsourced bpo, bpo companies"

Shown in image:
[image]

can someone help me identify the correct xpath/selector to use? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add images of code or HTML. Add it as a code block, instead. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath would be `page.locator("meta[@name='keywords']"`.

The XPath you provided was good but you forgot to add the `@` before the attribute's name `name`.

Comment: Tried to edit and add @ but I got this error: expect.toHaveAttribute: Unsupported token "@name" while parsing selector "meta[@name='keywords']"

Comment: What technical stack do you use? Because it is weird that a selenium based automation can't support `@name` in a findElement by XPath

Comment: It seems `page.locator` is coming from Playwright. You should try the following `page.locator(\`[name='keywords']\`);`

Comment: Tried and edited based from your comment but still not working:`Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(received).toHaveAttribute(expected)

Expected string: "Unient, bpo company, outsource company, bpo company philippines, bpo outsource, one outsource, offshoring australia, outsourcing philippines, outsourced bpo, bpo companies."
Received string: ""
Call log:
  - expect.toHaveAttribute with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for locator('[name=\'keywords\']')`

Comment: But you confirm you are on Playwright? Which language? Are you sure your automation is on the right page when test is failing?

Comment: Yes Im using playwright. My step scenario is view the view page source and locate the meta keywords. Somehow I was able to locate the meta description but not the meta keywords on which I am confused on why I cant locate it

Comment: Maybe you can target the head element and then the meta child element, like this: https://thats-it-code.com/playwright/playwright__find-locate-search-elements-tags/#playwright-get-the-child-element

Answer (score 0):

An XPath expression is evaluated relative to a "context node", unless the XPath expression begins with `/` in which case it starts from the root of the document. An expression like `meta[@name='keywords']` will return a `meta` element only if the context node is a `head` element which contains such a `meta` element nested directly inside it.

I don't know what context node applies in your case, but probably the simplest thing would be to create a full XPath, starting from the document node (`/`), like so:

```xml
/html/head/meta[@name='keywords']
```